# NiFi CaptureChangeMySQL converts varchar columns to nulls

Tags: apache-nifi

I have problem with Apache NiFi 1.12.1. For some unknown for me reason CaptureChangeMySQL returns many nulls. Basically, only columns which are int, return correct values. I'm new in a matter of using NiFi so I might miss some obvious thing in configuration.

I have following table:

```
create table inventory.abc
(
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    first_name varchar(100) not null,
    last_name varchar(100) not null,
    age int not null
);
```

Processor config:
[image]

Bin logs settings:

```
mysql> show variables like '%bin%';
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name                              | Value                          |
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| bind_address                               | *                              |
| binlog_cache_size                          | 32768                          |
| binlog_checksum                            | CRC32                          |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates    | OFF                            |
| binlog_error_action                        | ABORT_SERVER                   |
| binlog_format                              | ROW                            |
| binlog_group_commit_sync_delay             | 0                              |
| binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count    | 0                              |
| binlog_gtid_simple_recovery                | ON                             |
| binlog_max_flush_queue_time                | 0                              |
| binlog_order_commits                       | ON                             |
| binlog_row_image                           | FULL                           |
| binlog_rows_query_log_events               | OFF                            |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                     | 32768                          |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size | 25000                          |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking     | COMMIT_ORDER                   |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                   | OFF                            |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog             | OFF                            |
| log_bin                                    | ON                             |
| log_bin_basename                           | /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin       |
| log_bin_index                              | /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.index |
| log_bin_trust_function_creators            | OFF                            |
| log_bin_use_v1_row_events                  | OFF                            |
| log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog           | ON                             |
| max_binlog_cache_size                      | 18446744073709547520           |
| max_binlog_size                            | 1073741824                     |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size                 | 18446744073709547520           |
| sql_log_bin                                | ON                             |
| sync_binlog                                | 1                              |
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
29 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And I get results like this:
[image]

Any idea why I get so many nulls in output? I thought it might be related to `Distributed Map Cache Client` but since this option is not mandatory I don't think that's a problem.

Comment: but columns in the picture and table creation statement do not conform.

Comment: Yeah. That's also a problem. Columns name are converted into position ID while varchar columns are converted into null

Comment: What if you only cast varchar columns such as `CAST(first_name AS CHAR) AS first_name` and `CAST(last_name AS CHAR) AS last_name` ..?